# How to import external jars in command line or Atom?

Tags: java, atom-editor

I have been using IntelliJ to run my java programs that require some external jars. I also learned that if I want to compile and run my program from the command line I should do the following:

```
java -classpath someJar.jar YourMainClass
```

or for many libraries:

```
java -classpath someJar.jar;myJar.jar YourMainClass
```

However, while placed in the src folder where my class it doesn't seem to find my class. 
I also like using the Atom text editor but I don't know any package that can import external libraries like an IDE does. So how do I do it in Atom or in cmd in Windows 10? I am kind of a newbie to java dev outisde my beloved IDE, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You should learn to use Maven or Gradle, which handle this (and much more) for you.

Comment: Oh I will look that up, thanks @chrylis!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Windows system then try compiling (with the jar) using the following command in cmd:

```
javac -cp .;jar-name.jar *.java
```

To run the command with the jar use:

```
java -cp .;jar-name.jar JavaCodeName
```

If you're on a Unix system then you can try the following to compile in terminal:

```
javac -cp jar-name.jar:. *.java
```

And to run it use:

```
java -cp jar-name.jar:. JavaCodeName
```

I'm not too familiar with Atom so I don't know if there is an attachment to do this, but it should work for terminal / command prompt.